# How to check auth in https cloud function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to check auth object from client that called firebase https cloud function to achive following tasks:

1) Only allow authed users with verified email call https endpoint, otherwise return 403.

2) Somehow gain access to uid of client that called a function in order to set node like `characters/:uid` in database.

Reason for this is to disallow duplicate characters. I can manually pass `uid` in req.body, but this means that anyone could fiddle with this and create 100 different characters by sending any sort of uid as `req.body` payload.

Only work around I can think of for this is changing this logic to database triggers i.e. client writes to database `void/characters/uid` node (database rules do this whole validation) then function listens to this change in database, processes data and pushes it to `characters/uid`

But this means additional logic like removing node after it is done is needed, plus I am not sure how to send back error or success response back to client, as with https functions we can just `res.send(200)` or send back error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this, I think this can be done by firebase rules.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location

In the example provided, a rule like :

```
".write": "auth.uid === $user"
```

Would only allow authenticated users with the same uid as appears on the path to write data there.

I am uncertain if a 403 is returned. This implies that you are using firebase authentication, which is [covered in some depth here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), depending on the mechanism you are using for authentication.

Comment: Using rules is really the right answer here, if you do want to add authorization to an end-point we have an example on Github https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint